# Running two Django project in the same server , or use a new one?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, centos, python, django

I already have created one Django project in an Apache server using CentOS 7 , python3... Now I have to create another django project and I wonder if I should add this project in the same server or in a new Server . What's the advantages and disadvantages of each way? any advise?

Answer (score 0):

See this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites

Django provides a "sites" framework that allows a single Django instance to support multiple web sites.

Comment: Thank's for your answer Mike , but my two projects are independent of each other , they don't share the same DB or anything , unlike in the link that you post